# Is there a way to remove all weight paint on an object/armature?

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I set automatic weight paint from an armature to an object, but I wanna undo it but it won't let me ctrl+z that far back? So... can I get rid of ALL weight paint without using the subtract brush ? Like just clear absolutely every paint. My character's hair mesh intersects with the arm mesh just a bit, so the paint for the arm bone got on the hair mesh, and it's moving the hair wherever the arm is, and it looks bad, lol.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can clear the vertex groups (data tab in the properties panel). But be careful : you may have other groups than the groups which handle the weight paint... (the names of the groups you want to remove correspond to the names of the bones of your armature)

Comment: Comments are not for answers, please answer the question as an answer so it can be voted on appropriately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, only way I was able to re-rig with all the old armature removed and start from scratch was to delete the bones that get created on the object itself, one at a time:[image]

Comment: Rather than clicking the little minus a ton of times, you can click that little black arrow below the minus and "delete all groups". Learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

You can control bone weights in the Data tab of the Properties window:

[image]

Under the "Vertex Groups" section it lists every bone weight. If you go into edit mode, you can assign vertices to the groups directly without weight painting, or remove them from groups. This is great for cleaning up mistakes done in weight paint mode.
It's very helpful to turn on the "show weights" option in the 3D viewport, so you can quickly notice erroneous weights. You can turn this feature on/off in the 3D viewport options ('N' hotkey).